# SQL Server: can a transaction deadlock on COMMIT?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

Imagine a SQL Server transaction with e.g. two atomic SQL statements, **A** and **B**.

```
begin tran

insert into .. (**A**)

update .. (**B**)

commit tran
```

Either **A** or **B** is liable to cause a deadlock - if either does and if our transaction is chosen as the deadlock victim then too bad - we cannot continue.

Now imagine we get to this point in the script without a deadlock occurring:

```
--all done except for:
commit tran
```

Is it possible for a deadlock to occur here? i.e. *after* all the actual inserts/deletes/updates/whatever have been run, can a deadlock occur on `COMMIT`?

Comment: Probably not. The engine is optimized to assume transactions will be committed, so the commit is basically a formality, writing in the transaction log that all went well -- it's rollbacks that are expensive. I say "probably not" because it seems likely a commit does need to take certain internal latches, and in *theory* there might be a deadlock with another commit if those are not always taken in the same order, but it would be very weird, to say the least, if the engine was designed with a design flaw like that. Better question, probably: how do you think knowing this will benefit you?

Answer (score 1):

**No, I do not believe this is possible.**

At commit time, all locks that need to be taken have already been taken. The only things that need to be done are to commit the transaction log (make it durable), which only requires a latch. As I understand it, latches do not deadlock.

---

**There is one possible issue:**

When running under `SNAPSHOT` isolation, it is possiblt to get an update conflict

```
Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict.
```

This is not a deadlock, although it has similar effects, causing a complete transaction abortion.